# Firebase push doesn't add but replace (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, firebase

I'm having following code to add remarks ('opm') to a person ('leerling').

```
function onFormSubmitted()
{
    event.preventDefault();

    var ref = new Firebase("https://mydatabase.firebaseio.com/");
    var _leerling = document.getElementById("Leerling").value;
    var _opmerking = document.getElementById("Opmerking").value;

    var postsRef = ref.child("opmerkingen");
    var newPostRef = postsRef.push({
        leerling: _leerling,
        opmerking: _opmerking
    });

    var postID = newPostRef.key();
    var leerlingRef = ref.child("leerling").child(_leerling);

    leerlingRef.once('value', function(snapshot) {

        if( snapshot.val() === null ) {
            /* does not exist */

            var leerlingNummer = _leerling.substring(0,6).trim();
            ref.child("leerling").child(leerlingNummer).set({
                    "naam": _leerling.substring(7,33).trim(),
                    "klas": _leerling.substring(34,38)
            })
            ref.child("leerling").child(leerlingNummer).child("opmerkingen").push({
                "opmID": postID
            })

        } else {
            var leerlingPostRef = snapshot.ref().child("opmerkingen)");
            leerlingPostRef.push({"opmID": postID});
        }
    });
}
```

At the beginning of the code postsRef.push ADDS a remark to the opmerkingen child (in the root), as intended.

At the end of the code I do the same as far as I am aware (leerlingPostRef.push) for the opmerkingen child of the leerling, but there the whole opmerkingen child get REPLACED, deleting the existing opm: postID instead of adding one.

What is wrong and how to solve?

Comment: So you're just trying to update the value of opmID for Leerling?

Comment: I guess. the content of leerling should remain intact, only a remark should be ADDED

Comment: I suggest using Firebase.update(). Check my answer for a little more elaboration.

Comment: Is this just a typo in your post? `var leerlingPostRef = snapshot.ref().child("opmerkingen)");`. Specifically, the extra `)` here: `.child("opmerkingen)");` Or is this in your code as well?

Comment: this error was actually also in the original code! However unfortunately it doesn't solve the issue...

Comment: push() creates a new, unique id and sets the data in there. If a parent of that path is a primitve (string, etc) then it will be "replaced" as it will become an object. However, push() can't, by definition, replace an existing parent node. A read of the API and [guide](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/saving-data.html) could start you off on the right foot here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I passed leerling from a regular input type='text' field it worked fine but when I passed it from a select-option input field it failed as described.

Solution:

```
var leerlingRef = ref.child("leerling").child(_leerling.substring(0,6).trim());
```

instead of

```
var leerlingRef = ref.child("leerling").child(_leerling);
```

on line 15

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using `Firebase.update()` as it will either create or update a value. Using `Firebase.push()` removes any, and all data at a certain sub-tree is removed and replaced with what you sent.

So just replace any reference of `Firebase.push()` with `Firebase.update()` and your code should work as expected.

Link for ref: [Firebase.update()](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/update.html)

Note: This will replace any reference of the data that you are updating. So if you have the value `"opmID": 1` in Firebase, updating `"opmID"` to `2` would replace the original `"opmID": 1`. As Firebase acts like a dictionary, keys can only exist once.

Comment: I replaced the two instances of push at the end of the code now with update. But it doesn't make a difference, Whole opmerkingen child is still replaced containing only the new opmerking?

Comment: Look at line 10 where you define `newPostRef`. You're updating `opmerkingen` with new information. So every time you call this function `opmerkingen` will be replaced with the new information in those variables.

Comment: @TaylorGlaeser Maybe I am misunderstanding you, but it sounds like you're mixing up `Firebase.push()` with `Firebase.set()`. The `Firebase.set()` method will overwrite data at a location, while `Firebase.push()` generates a new child location with a unique key.

Comment: @Seamus You're right, I was getting my methods mixed up. So OP, are you wanting to add ANOTHER opm (remark) to the sub-tree or are you wishing to update the EXISTING opm (remark)?

Comment: add another one. still no luck so far. furthermore reference to opmerkingen child you mention (line 10) is as far as I understand not related to the opmerkingen child of leerling (later in the code). Just to make sure a changed the name of the opmerkingen child of leerling and that didn't make a difference to the issue.

Comment: When I run your code as-is, from your original post, my Firebase tree looks to work as you want it. [Here's](http://imgur.com/lvozwu1) what my Firebase looks like. Every time I update, Both the `/leerling/test/opmerkingen` tree and the `/opmkerkingen` tree is updated. Nothing is removed.

Comment: Can you tell me how exactly you run it? I tried to put the code in JSFiddle but I am not familiar with that. Just tells me 'Forbidden (403). CSRF verification failed. Request aborted. More information is available with DEBUG=True.' but I have no idea what to do with that message.

Comment: When I isolate the code from the html source file I find it actually works as you found out! What woud be the best way to proceed with this issue. Close this discussion (with the issue not solved for me actually) or add the complete code...?

Comment: I'd say let's try to resolve the issue. Let's create 2 JSFiddles. Go ahead and create a JSFiddle with the failing code (the one that returns the 403 error) and set the flag DEBUG=True. Create a second JSFiddle with your complete code from this individual webpage, with all sensitive information redacted, and post a link to both JSFiddles in a comment. To generate a JSFiddle link, just click save at the top (it will redirect to a permalink page) after you're done entering in all the code.

Comment: Good news, I now finally isolated the issue... When I passed leerling from a regular input type='text' field it worked fine but when I passed it from a select-option input field it fails as described. Solution:  var leerlingRef = ref.child("leerling").child(_leerling.substring(0,6).trim()); instead of  var leerlingRef = ref.child("leerling").child(_leerling); on line 15!

Comment: Well that's great! Glad to know that you figured out the issue.