# Firebase push doesn't add but replace

Tags: javascript, firebase

When I add a `opmerking` to a child node called 'leerling' using `.push()`, the new node is actually added without a problem but unintentionally the existing `opmerking` node is replaced in the process.

I has a similar issue before, see post [Firebase push doesn't add but replace (JavaScript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29377925/firebase-push-doesnt-add-but-replace-javascript) which was then resolved, but that solution doesn't apply here.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/ruud00000/qod27op8/4/) is a fiddle of the complete source code. Please just change the firebase database name to your own (or is there a test/demo database available?) in order to test it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
    $("#submit").click(function(){
        var _leerling = $("#Leerling").val();
        var _opmerking = $("#Opmerking").val();
        var _bestanden = $("#Bestanden").val();
        var _door = $("#Door").val();
        var success = true;

        if(
            _leerling == "Maak een keuze..." || _leerling == "" || _leerling == "5H:" || _leerling == "6V:" || 
            _opmerking == "Typ hier jouw opmerking over de leerling die je geselecteerd hebt." || _opmerking == "" || 
            _door == "Maak een keuze..." || _door == "" 
            ) {
            alert("Alle velden met * zijn verplicht");      
        }
        else {
            event.preventDefault();
            var ref = new Firebase("https://torrid-inferno-6428.firebaseio.com/");
            var leerlingNummer = _leerling.substring(0,6).trim();
            var updatedObj = {}; // truc om key een waarde te geven, kan niet rechtstreeks met JavaScript
            updatedObj[leerlingNummer] = {              
                "naam": _leerling.substring(7,33).trim(),
                "klas": _leerling.substring(34,38),
                "klaskort": _leerling.substring(35,37),
                "leerlingdropdown": _leerling};
            ref.child("leerling").update(updatedObj,
                function(data) {
                    if (data) { alert(data); success = false; }
                });

            ref.child("leerling").child(leerlingNummer).child("opmerkingen").push({
                "opmerking": _opmerking,
                "bestanden": _bestanden,
                "door": _door},
                function(data) {
                    if (data) { alert(data); success = false; }
                    if (success) { 
                        alert("Bedankt! Jouw opmerking is opgeslagen.");
                        $('#form')[0].reset(); //To reset form fields
                    }

                });

        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem isn't with `Firebase.push()`, but here:

```
var updatedObj = {}; // truc om key een waarde te geven, kan niet rechtstreeks met JavaScript
updatedObj[leerlingNummer] = {              
    "naam": _leerling.substring(7,33).trim(),
    "klas": _leerling.substring(34,38),
    "klaskort": _leerling.substring(35,37),
    "leerlingdropdown": _leerling};

ref.child("leerling").update(updatedObj, 
    function(data) {
        if (data) { alert(data); success = false; }
});
```

You are updating `/leerling/<leerlingNummer>`, which means that no other children of `/leerling` will be changed. But, you are replacing everything under `/leerling/<leerlingNummer>`, and that's what is deleting your `opmerkingen`.

Try this instead:

```
var updatedObj = {              
    "naam": _leerling.substring(7,33).trim(),
    "klas": _leerling.substring(34,38),
    "klaskort": _leerling.substring(35,37),
    "leerlingdropdown": _leerling};

ref.child("leerling").child(leerlingNummer).update(updatedObj, function(data) {
        if (data) { alert(data); success = false; }
});
```

This will update the specified child nodes of `/leerling/<leerlingNummer>`.

Comment: Good catch Seamus! You beat me by 6 minutes. :-)

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks. Sometimes I get lucky. :)